# how to open excel file in eclipse internal editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to open excel file from project explorer in eclipse internal editor. I am calling below function to open file in editor.

```
public static void openFileIntoEditor(String filePath) {
    File fileToOpen = new File(filePath);
    if (fileToOpen.exists() && fileToOpen.isFile()) {
        try {
            IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(fileToOpen.toURI());
            IWorkbenchPage page = GUIHandler.getPage();
            try {
                IDE.openInternalEditorOnFileStore(page, fileStore);
                //IDE.openEditorOnFileStore(page, fileStore);
            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                System.out.println("ERORR in openFileIntoEditor : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERORR in openFileIntoEditor2 : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
    }
}
```

It works fine for text file but shows some binary code when i am trying to open excel file in internal editor. Where i am doing wrong or what should i need to do to open excel file in internal Eclipse editor by java program.

Answer (score 0):

There is no internal editor for Excel files in standard Eclipse. So you are just getting the normal text editor trying to edit a binary file.

You could try `IDE.openEditorOnFileStore`, this may open an 'in-place System Editor` within Eclipse (you need to have the 'Allow in-place system editors' option set in the Preferences on the 'General > Editors' page).

Answer (score 0):

If the excel file is not corrupted, you can just double click on it to open it in the editor. 
For reading or writing of excel files, you should use the apache poi framework.

https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

Comment: I need to open excel file by java program